# Background app with react native and bare workflow expo

Tags: react-native, expo, background-task

I need to use expo (with simple workflow) in react native development, because I want to test my application on Android and IOS and I don't have a MAC to do that (my operating system: windows 10). However, I still don't know which tool to use to make my app ALWAYS work in the background, even if the user closes the app or restarts the phone. I've tried using the react-native-background-timer, but when compiling, the error always returns:

***TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNBackgroundTimer.start').***

The documentation for react-native-background-timer states that, in case this error occurs, I must make the link manually. I made the link, but the error continues.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to perform tasks in the background with the bare workflow expo? If this is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the useful link for the expo background task execution
[expo background task](https://chafikgharbi.com/expo-background-task/)